# Templating SuperTable

Tags: matrix, plugins, table, plugin-supertable

I'm using the SuperTable plugin to create Matrix fields inside a super Table. It's looking great in the front-end but I can't find any documentation on how to template the fields. This is my code so far:

```
            <div class="article-blocks">
            {% for block in entry.informasjon %}

                {% if block.type == "innhold" %}

                    {% for row in entry.velg1Av3BildeVideo %}

                        <div class="image-container">
                            {% for image in entry.bilde1 %}
                                <img src="/{{ image.getUrl('artikkelBlokk1Lite') }}" alt="{{ image.title }}" />
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% for image in entry.bilde2 %}
                                <img src="/{{ image.getUrl('artikkelBlokk1Stor') }}" alt="{{ image.title }}" />
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>

                    {% endfor %}     

                {% endif %}  

            {% endfor %}
            </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried getting in touch with the plugin author? https://github.com/engram-design/SuperTable

Answer (score 8):

There's no block types with SuperTable, so no need to check that. Other that that it works just the same as Matrix fields.

```
{% for row in superTableField %}
    {{ row.textFieldInSuperTableField }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few templating examples via the documentation - https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/super-table/docs/guides/templating-examples

But as @carlcs states, I believe the issue is that you're checking `{% if block.type == "innhold" %}` which will fail, as a SuperTableBlock doesn't have an attribute `type` at all, unlike Matrix.